# Issues with For Loop

Tags: php, forms, dynamic

i am just now learning on php, this is my training period ,
so please help me with,
   how to store form data in a array without database in php

thank you

Comment: Your question and title need work. Significantly. [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is your first port of call, then you can edit your question such that we can answer it.

Comment: `$student[]= array($_POST['nsme'], $_POST['std'], $_POST['class'])`

Comment: Honestly, do you think your question makes any sense?

Comment: What is the ' `i` ' at the end of the code ?? Question should more understandable with a brief description

Comment: Please describe what exactly you want to do and what goes wrong. Describe your expected output. Good start is to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not structure very well.

Your for loop has syntax errors in it. For examples on how to do a for loop look at http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php they explain it very well.

```
$student=array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
       $student[$i]= $_POST['nsme']+$_POST['std']+$_POST['class'];
}
```

I think something like that might be what you are looking for but its unclear in the question.